# ros1_bridge not finding generated message .hpp file

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My directory structure is as recommended by the documentation:

```
.
├─ ros1_ws
│  └─ src
│     └─ bridge_msgs
│        └─ msg
│           └─ MyMessage.msg
├─ ros2_ws
│  └─ src
│     └─ bridge_msgs
│        ├─ msg
│           └─ MyMessage.msg
└─ bridge
   └─ src
      └─ ros1_bridge
```

When building, I get the following error

```
In file included from bridge/build/ros1_bridge/generated/get_factory.cpp:9:
bridge/build/ros1_bridge/generated/bridge_msgs_factories.hpp:13:10: fatal error: bridge_msgs/msg/my_message.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <bridge_msgs/msg/my_message.hpp>
```

I inspected `ros1_bridge/generated/bridge_msgs__msg__MyMessage__factories.cpp` and it contains the relevant mapping (not dummy).

Also, the relevant `my_message.hpp` file has been generated beforehand in

```
./ros2_ws/install/bridge_msgs/include/bridge_msgs/msg/my_message.hpp
./ros2_ws/build/bridge_msgs/rosidl_generator_cpp/bridge_msgs/msg/my_message.hpp
```

I've tried multiple clean rebuilds of all workspaces, sourcing and building `bridge` last

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357099/ros1_bridge-not-finding-generated-message-.hpp-file/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems before sourcing, I should clean all ROS related environment variables first.  This solved my problem

```
unset $(env | grep "ROS_\|AMENT_\|COLCON_\|CATKIN_" | egrep -o '^[^=]+')
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0